# how can I make a 2D sprite to become a button and when I press it, it renders another sprite? Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

How can I make a sprite become a trigger to rendering another sprite ?

the method I did was to add a sprite but disable the renderer

and added a touch input module, event trigger and added a script to enable the rendering once the touch input is catched.

it doesn't work.

I dont know if the script is wrong, or the way I add components for the triggers are wrong. i tried alot of combinations but I failed. the image I want to render after the touch is pre-rendered as soon as I launch the app
[here is the last setting I tried and failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdTQH.png)

thank you in advanced